# VBA - Saving a file - Determine file path based partially on cell values

Tags: excel, vba, filepath

Everything works as it should until I get to the ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs line, where I get a Run-time error 1004.

`Sub Tester()

```
Dim qNum, fldr As String
Dim custName As String
Dim myFileName As String
Dim completePath As String
Dim division As String

custName = Range("B12").Value
qNum = Range("B19").Value

If custName = "CNUL - Albian" Then
    custName = "CNRL"
    division = "Albian"
End If
If custName = "CNUL - Horizon" Then
    custName = "CNRL"
    division = "Horizon"
End If
If custName = "CNRL - Albian" Then
    custName = "CNRL"
    division = "Albian"
End If
If custName = "CNRL - Horizon" Then
    custName = "CNRL"
    division = "Horizon"
End If

If custName = "CNRL" Then
    fldr = GetMatchingPathCNRL(qNum, custName, division) '<< find the        matching folder
    If Len(fldr) > 0 Then
        Debug.Print "Found folder for customer=" & custName & _
                        ", Qnum=" & qNum & vbLf & fldr
            '...use this path

    Else
        MsgBox "No matching folder!", vbExclamation
    End If
Else
    fldr = GetMatchingPath(qNum, custName) '<< find the matching folder
    If Len(fldr) > 0 Then
        Debug.Print "Found folder for customer=" & custName & _
                    ", Qnum=" & qNum & vbLf & fldr
        '...use this path

    Else
        MsgBox "No matching folder!", vbExclamation
    End If
End If


myFileName = custName & " " & qNum & " " & "MTO Rev A"
completePath = fldr & "\" & myFileName

ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=completePath
End Sub

Function GetMatchingPath(qNum, custName) As String
Const ROOT As String = "P:\MyCompany\" '<< adjust to suit
Dim f
f = Dir(ROOT & custName & "\*" & qNum & "*", vbDirectory)
GetMatchingPath = ROOT & custName & "\" & f
End Function


Function GetMatchingPathCNRL(qNum, custName, division) As String
Const ROOT As String = "P:\MyCompany\" '<< adjust to suit
Dim f
f = Dir(ROOT & custName & "\" & division & "\*" & qNum & "*", vbDirectory)
GetMatchingPathCNRL = ROOT & custName & "\" & f
End Function
```

`
It's finding the filepath way correctly and looks as if it should complete the save in the right location, but I'm always getting a 1004 error. Any ideas?

Comment: `Dir("C:\Folders\Q-180575*")` (for example) should work, assuming there's not a folder named (eg) "Q-1805759..."

Comment: Yes, there is a way.  Start with [Reading values from a Cell](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-value-property-excel), then look into [String Manipulation](https://www.excel-easy.com/vba/string-manipulation.html), and checkout [SaveAs method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/workbook-saveas-method-excel).  If you run into any errors come back and post them, with the code you've tried.  We'll all be waiting, Good Luck  :)

Comment: Thanks for the responses. This is my attempt so far but it is not working.


Public Sub SaveWorkbook()

Dim custName As String
Dim quoteNum As String
Dim myFilename As String
Dim myFilePath As String

custName = Range("B12")
quoteNum = Range("B19")
myFilePath = "P:\MyCompany\custName\quoteNum*\2-Engineering\2.3 - Material Take Off\"
myFilename = quoteNum & "- " & custName

ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs filename:=myFilePath & myFilename & ".xlsm", FileFormat:=xlNormal

End Sub

Comment: Your Path `myFilePath = "P:\MyCompany\custName\quoteNum*\2-Engineering\2.3 - Material Take Off\"` has an Asterisk in it, and it's probably not too happy with that, but I tested it with C:\Temp\ and it worked fine.

Comment: Tim Williams suggested above that adding the asterisk would match the folder with partial info. Should I not use the asterisk in that line?

Comment: Asterisk won't work in the path the way you have it, the Dir function understands how to use it, so you'd have to incorporate it. `myFilePath = Dir("P:\MyCompany\custName\" & quoteNum & "*", vbDirectory)`

Comment: Ok I see what you mean. What you wrote for myFilePath doesn't quite work, but I tried the following: `myFilePath = Dir("P:\MyCompany\custName\" & quoteNum & "*" & "\2-Engineering\2.3 - Material Take Off\", vbDirectory)`. Is this the right way to use Dir/vbDirectory? It's still not saving.

Answer (score 0):

To show the basic principle:

**EDIT**: a few changes to your code...

```
Sub Tester()

    Dim qNum, fldr
    Dim custName

    custName = Range("B12").Value
    qNum = Range("B19").Value

    fldr = GetMatchingPath(qNum, custName) '<< find the matching folder
    If Len(fldr) > 0 Then

        Debug.Print "Found folder for customer=" & custName & _
                    ", Qnum=" & qNum & vblf & fldr
        '...use this path

    Else
        MsgBox "No matching folder!", vbExclamation
    End If

End Sub

'get the path for a given q number
Function GetMatchingPath(qNum, custName) As String
    Const ROOT As String = "P:\Weir\" '<< adjust to suit
    Dim f

    f = Dir(ROOT & custName & "\" & qNum & "*", vbDirectory)
    GetMatchingPath = ROOT & custName & "\" & f
End Function
```

Comment: Ok I tried implementing this but it doesn't seem to be holding any values for f. Looking at the Locals menu and stepping through, the value for f went from "empty" to "". Any ideas?

Comment: If `f` has no value following the call to `Dir()` then there was no folder which matched the value you provided.  Can you update your question with the exact code you tried?

Comment: Sure. The folder I want to save my file in has the path `P:\MyCompany\Syncrude\Q-188888 - 32in Spool\2-Engineering\2.3-Material Take Off`. In B12 I have "Syncrude", in B19 I have "Q-188888". The code i have is as follows:

Comment: Under your question, click the "Edit" link, copy and paste your code from the VB editor into the bottom of your question, select it, and then use the "{}" button to format it as code.

Comment: Hi Tim Williams, thanks for all the help with this but it is still not quite right. As I step through the code the variable f is still not storing a value, meaning no folder matched the value. I'm not sure how that can be as the folder path I'm testing with is _P:\MyCompany\Syncrude\TEST Q-188888_. Any thoughts as to why f doesn't want to store a value?

Comment: Aren't all your folders named something like "Q-333335 other text here" (i.e. the names all **start** with the Q number)?  What's with "TEST Q-188888" ?  If the Q number can be *anywhere* in the folder name then you'd need something like `Dir(ROOT & custName & "\*" & qNum & "*", vbDirectory)` (note the extra wildcard asterisk before the Q number)

Comment: Ahh sorry I didn't realize the Q-number couldn't be anywhere in the file name. That fixed it. Thanks!

Comment: I've adapted the code you gave me to do a few extra things that I wanted it to do, but now I am getting a 1004 error. Any idea why this may be happening?

Comment: @DaveFriesen - at this point you should really start a new question: otherwise this whole page starts to make no sense to someone coming along later.